# What's the difference of click and focus event between mobile devices and Computers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mobile, focus

I realize the function of this : jump to next input after finishing this input that's focused (just need one charactor). And it does work on computer.
I need to realize that when someone input a charactor like "a" through keyboard , and it will focus on the next input . I know how to realize it on computers.

```
if ($(this).val().length === 1){
   $(this).next().focus();
}
```

And I know keyup method to bind this.
But on mobile phones something bad happended: 
 It dosen't work on mobiles and Virtual keyboard of phones will **hide** after input .
I heard there is 300ms delay after click on the phone . How to trigger focus or click immediately on mobile devices?

```
<input type="text" >
<input type="text" >
<input type="text" >
<input type="text" >
```

Comment: `$(this).next.focus();` **==>** `$(this).next().focus();` note `()` of `next` I wonder _"And it does work on computer."_

Comment: and you might look into `input` event instead.

Comment: Sorry ,it is a  slightest slip of attention . But it is `next()` on my code. @Tushar

Comment: @Jai Would you tell me where to look up input event? Thank you!

Comment: @yaochiqkl can you update your question with your code?

Comment: @Jai You mean the whole code of my javascript files? It is a little bit of complex .  Is it because of my code errors , instead of difference of computers and mobile devices?  Thx for your reminding

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery keyup's](https://api.jquery.com/keyup/) method should works fine.

Try something like this:

```js
$.each($(".input"),function(){
 $(this).keyup(function() {
             $(this).next().focus();
        });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="input" type="text" />
<input class="input" type="text" />
<input class="input" type="text" />
```

Comment: I know using keyup method to realize it  and it work well on computer , but  not on mobiles :'(

Comment: Hmmm, I tried this snippet on my mobile (in jsfiddle) and it's working: http://jsfiddle.net/s2pL450L

Comment: Oh really?  I'll check it again ,thanks all the same